# Can food be described as "nice"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage

Can food be described as 'nice'?

> This food is nice;
>   This dish is nice.

I always thought it could be, but I was speaking to a few friends and they argued (and strongly may I add) otherwise.

Comment: Well, how can we know without learning what the food was? Maybe it wasn’t very nice.

Comment: Let's say both parties agree that the food is tasty!

Comment: Yes. Food can also be described as [mean](http://meangreenhotsauce.com/).

Comment: @tchrist That casserole insulted my mother; I had no choice but to challenge it to a duel. It thought I would be impressed with it's choice of weapon (spoon); and while the brave casserole fought well - I was victorious on the field. I have sent the orphans some small money and to stay with their uncle...

Comment: Have you checked the meaning of *nice* in a dictionary?

Comment: Could you maybe add the argument they offered against using "nice" to describe food?

Comment: I think besides being nice, food can be fun too! http://books.google.com/books?id=VKZlHAAACAAJ

Comment: Are your friends native speakers? What was their argument against the word *nice*? Sometimes the word, nice, can mean the exact opposite especially if the food wasn't good at all!

Comment: Niceness is in the eye of the beholder. It is actually nice that we have food that we can opine about. Dickens' orphans in the workhouse got gruel. 'Everyday we say a prayer, Will they change the Bill of Fayre, But still we get the same old gruel...' Try this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEQDllvuy1I

Comment: If this question were asked by someone who had attended the same school as – I'm going to risk _me_ – I'd guess they'd been told in some English (or even German) lesson "Use 'nice' very sparingly if at all: there are alternatives with far better style. Delicious food, a pleasant personality, a beautiful view, a stylish car . . ." So not 'wrong' but often not the best choice. However, I wouldn't dream of tinkering with Tommy Cooper's (ironic) "That's _nice_, that is!"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you remember the sugary biscuits that used to have the letters NICE on them. I never knew whether to pronounce it nice, or neece (like the French city) as someone once told me that that was their origin Of course the acronym NICE has acquired an altogether more sombre meaning in today's Britain - the National Institute for Clinical Excellence - a euphemism if ever there was one.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, but again considered 'Nice' not the best choice. The city is very nice, in my opinion.

Comment: Both those examples sound very wrong to me. You very rarely want to use 'nice' with food. 'good' is better. The rare instance is in the context of the example 'nice cup of tea' (and that is very British sounding to me (AmE).

Comment: @Mitch  'Nice' may be considered inane, but it is high literacy compared to 'cute'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Nice" is used to describe food ... whenever the food deserves that qualification!

OED (1994 edition)

14.Of food; Dainty, appetizing. *spec*. of a cup of tea.

> 1712 Arbuthnot J. Bull iii. App. i, *This was but a pretence to provide some nice bit for himself*.
>   a1766 F. Sheridan Sidney Bidulph V. 193 *We sent her up three or four plates of the nicest things that were at table*.
>   1799 Jane Austen Lett. (1884) I. 224 *You must give us something very nice, for we are used to live well*.
>   1852 Rock Ch. of Fathers III. 103 *A banquet which usually consisted of the nicest dishes then known*.
>   1853 A. Soyer Pantroph. 284 *Some of these pastries would appear very nice to us in the present day*.
>   1899 R. Whiteing No. 5 John St. iv. 38 *Her sex’s universal restorative... ‘You shall have a nice cup of tea*.’
>   1928 R. Knox Footsteps at Lock v. 41 *You’d have got a nice cup of tea down at the Gudgeon*.
>   1937 A. P. Herbert Nice Cup of Tea (song), *I like a nice cup of tea in the morning, For to start the day you see*.
>   1937 ‘G. Orwell’ Road to Wigan Pier v. 88 *There is generally a cup of tea going–a ‘nice cup of tea*’.
>   1961 I. Fleming Thunderball iv. 38 *The dimity world of the Nice-Cup-of-Tea*.
>   1974 L. Deighton Spy Story xxi. 221 ‘*I’ll pour him some tea,’ said Dawlish. ‘There’s nothing so reviving as a nice cup of tea*.’

and thousands of recent examples on the web :
[In a health book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=brHcQdNN-64C&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=%22some%20nice%20food%22&source=bl&ots=uu8dtXCQy3&sig=kgjBPMVI_yqt6XGSQ3Nm38E2dyw&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=d8nDUs28DqmV0AXY34DQDg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22some%20nice%20food%22&f=false):  *... when you are going to wish you had some nice food...*
[In Melbourne they have](http://www.thehappiesthour.com/blog/top-25-pubs-in-melbourne/): *nice food [pubs]*.
[A blog by a Yorkshire person](http://reallynicefood.com/rebecca): *Really nice food when nice food isn’t enough*.

Comment: 'nice food' sounds wrong in AmE. Maybe this is a British/Aussie thing?

Comment: @Mitch: *Nice food-service lacking* a Santa Barbara CA [ining review](http://www.santabarbara.com/dining/review_read.asp?pk_restaurant=1713). [Name of a restaurant in Kansas City](http://www.urbanspoon.com/r/34/1483832/restaurant/West-Kansas-City/Nice-Food-Kansas-City) and more to be found thanks to google... but you might not have any nice cuppas on the other side of the Pond.

Comment: Your first example sounds infelicitous to me. The second is the name of a Chinese restaurant, which are notorious for incongruities in naming/translation. I'm not saying you're wrong ('nice cup of tea' sounds just fine to me); I just want to give perspective for no-native speakers on how to use it. It sounds very grating in English to say: "Was your steak nice?", "Have your choice of nice jelly beans" or closer to the boundary "They have a nice slice of pizza." There might be bizarre circumstances where those all might be reasonable locutions, but that's unlikely for a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 4):

Since your question is about usage, yes, food can be described as 'nice' to mean that it tastes good.

But it is sometimes unacceptable amongst certain Asians (as I've experienced in the past) whose mother-tongue is not English.

While I used to teach in the Emirates, I had lunch with some Indian and Pakistani colleagues. They asked me how the food was and I said it was 'nice'. In response they choked and laughed while translating 'nice' as 'beautiful' in Hindi or Urdu.

So to them the usage was a little odd. However, it is correct and it is widely used.

Going one level further, a single word can be given new implied meanings depending on a given situation. Thus nice could mean: good, cool, beautiful, pleasant and so on...

In certain situation, the opposite is also suggested. For example, a kid jumping on the bed makes a mess. The father may say 'very nice' to mean *that's terrible, what do you think you're doing?*

But the bottom line, yes, you can say that food is nice.

Comment: I'm Indian - and a native English speaker - and I find absolutely nothing wrong with describing food as *nice*. Also, I don't think 'nice' translates to 'beautiful' in hindi *or* urdu. :)

Comment: @mikhailcazi: I think these people were interpreting *nice* in that sense because that was simply how they had learned it.

Comment: @Jon They ought to check in their OEDs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Many non-native speakers do not 'check in their OEDs', in fact, they may not have heard of the OED -- they learn from the Marms & Masters and more from the other non-native speakers. There's heavy influence of the first language as well. Why, consider the OP's case, the 'critics' were **not** native English speakers.

Comment: @Kris I thought that was implied in my comment.